# Choosing the Test Function Space when Deriving Weak Form of PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I'm trying to understand how to choose the space of test functions when deriving the weak form of a PDE. For my problem specifically, I have one Neumann boundary condition and one Dirichlet boundary condition. Here's the general form in the ODE case,

$$Lu(x)=f(x),\quad x\in (0,Z) \\u'(0)=a,\quad u(Z)=b.$$

I have seen lots of advice (e.g. [Test space for weak formulation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1744348/test-space-for-weak-formulation)) saying that the test function should exist in the same space as the weak solution but why is that? What is it about the boundary conditions that tell me what space the solution $u$ and the test solution $v$ should be in?

Comment: Depending on your operator $L$, this can be linked to the method use to derive the existence of a solution. If you use for instance Lax-Milgram or Riesz theorem, you need both functions in your weak form to lie in the same space (since you want them to play a sort of symmetric role in the weak form), hence this choice.